# Equation over multiple lines overshooting column width in two column format

Tags: spacing, equations, two-column

I am currently trying to have a system of equations plotted across multiple lines, but I am having an issue with doing this with a two column document format. Specifically it overshoots the width of the column, whereas I would like the portion of the equations (`\forall \textbf{x} \in \Omega`) to be in line with the column of text itself.

How can this be done? My document is below:

```
\documentclass[%
aip,
jcp,%
amsmath,amssymb,
a4paper,
%preprint,%
reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical
]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix}
xxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxxxxx xxx xx xx:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
\textrm{B}:&    \quad \rho c_p \frac{dT}{dt} =  -\kappa\Delta T \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \Omega \\
\textrm{S}:&    \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt} =   - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \quad && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega \\
\textrm{TS}:&   \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt}  =  \frac{(1-\mathcal{R})Pe^{-\tau}}{\pi w^2} e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{w^2}}  - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \\ & - \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}}\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{M}p(T)  \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega_t
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `widetext` environment to break out of two-column mode easily without having to do things like a `\clearpage`. This is done, using your example, like:

```tex
\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
\textrm{B}:&    \quad \rho c_p \frac{dT}{dt} =  -\kappa\Delta T \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \Omega \\
\textrm{S}:&    \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt} =   - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \quad && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega \\
\textrm{TS}:&   \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt}  =  \frac{(1-\mathcal{R})Pe^{-\tau}}{\pi w^2} e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{w^2}}  - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \\ & - \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}}\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{M}p(T)  \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega_t
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}
```

which generates something like the following:
[image]

Comment: This would make more (visual) sense if the last line, with the root, started to the right of the equal sign.  (There's enough room.)  This can most easily be done with a `\phantom`.